# How can I get my loop to keep re-entering new variables and operators to continue to calculate?

Tags: java

I am attempting to have the user enter in multiple values and the computer would then return the answer. For instance they would enter in 10 + 11 - 15 / 12 ? then the it would output the answer. I have tested this and it only will take the first number and the last operator and the last number entered and calculate that answer. (output from about would of been 10/12) From what I can tell my math methods are working correctly, but I have attached them as well. How can I get it to continue to read in new user inputs then do the math to figure out the answer?

This is my code:

```
static void evaluate (){
    // this loads a scanner and prompts the user for input
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the expression: ");     
    int answer = 0; 
    int num = 0;
    int input1, input2;
    char operator = '+' ;
    input1 = input.nextInt();
    operator = input.next().charAt(0);
    input2 = input.nextInt(); 
    if(operator == '?')
        return;
    //this loop will continue until ? is entered
    do{
    if(operator == '?')
        break;
    operator = input.next().charAt(0);
    input2 = input.nextInt(); 
    // this will detect which operator is used 
    switch (operator) {
        case '+': answer = addition(input1, input2);
                  break;
        case '-': answer = subtract(input1, input2);
                  break;
        case '*': answer = multiply(input1, input2);
                  break;
        case '/': answer = division(input1, input2);
                  break;
        case '%': answer = remainder(input1, input2);
    } } while (operator != '?'); 
    System.out.println("The result is " + answer);  
}
```

These are the methods for addition, subtraction, division, multiplication, and modulos.

```
// this is the math if a + is used as an operator
static int addition (int num1, int num2){
    int add;
    add = num1 + num2;
    return add;
}
// this is the math if a - is used as an operator
static int subtract (int num1, int num2){
    int minus;
    minus = num1 - num2;
    return minus;
}
// this is the math if a * is used as an operator
static int multiply (int num1, int num2){
    int multi;
    multi = num1 * num2;
    return multi;
}
// this is the math if a / is used as an operator
static int division (int num1, int num2){
    int div;
    div = num1 / num2;
    return div;
}
// this is the math if a % is used as an operator
static int remainder (int num1, int num2){
    int modulos;
    modulos = num1 % num2;
    return modulos;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is perfectly fine and all you have to do is put this condition `if(operator == '?') break;` after you read the value in `operator` by doing `operator = input.next().charAt(0);`.

One other thing is that you are never changing the value of `input1`. You should start assigning `answer` back to `input1` after performing any operation.

Here is the modified code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter The Expression: ");     
    int answer = 0, num = 0, input1, input2;
    char operator = '+' ;

    /* Read Input 1 */
    input1 = input.nextInt();

    //this loop will continue until ? is entered
    do {
        /* Read Operator */
        operator = input.next().charAt(0);
        if(operator == '?') break;
        /* Read Input 2 */
        input2 = input.nextInt(); 
        // this will detect which operator is used 
        switch (operator) {
            case '+': answer = addition(input1, input2);
                      break;
            case '-': answer = subtract(input1, input2);
                      break;
            case '*': answer = multiply(input1, input2);
                      break;
            case '/': answer = division(input1, input2);
                      break;
            case '%': answer = remainder(input1, input2);
        }
        /* Input1 will be the answer now */
        input1 = answer;
    } while (operator != '?'); 
    System.out.println("Result: " + answer);   
}

// this is the math if a + is used as an operator
static int addition (int num1, int num2){
    int add;
    add = num1 + num2;
    return add;
}
// this is the math if a - is used as an operator
static int subtract (int num1, int num2){
    int minus;
    minus = num1 - num2;
    return minus;
}
// this is the math if a * is used as an operator
static int multiply (int num1, int num2){
    int multi;
    multi = num1 * num2;
    return multi;
}
// this is the math if a / is used as an operator
static int division (int num1, int num2){
    int div;
    div = num1 / num2;
    return div;
}
// this is the math if a % is used as an operator
static int remainder (int num1, int num2){
    int modulos;
    modulos = num1 % num2;
    return modulos;
}
```

Input:

```
10 + 11 - 15 / 2 ?
```

Output:

```
Result: 3
```

Also, I hope you are putting white spaces between your input numbers like what you have shown in the question above. Note that with the way you are reading input `10 + 11 - 15 / 12 ?` will work fine but `10+11-15/12?` will not.

Comment: That is what I thought as well! but after I tried it, the loop will continue even if I enter in a ? and it will not compile the math. this is how it looks.          `operator = input.next().charAt(0);
            input2 = input.nextInt(); 
      if(operator == '?')
         break; ` also I have been putting in white spaces between each

Comment: @154guy No, it will not continue the loop. There is a problem with the way you read input. You are never updating `input1`. See the updated solution.

Comment: When I entered in the code that you provided at http://ideone.com/pJR5lY it says there is an error in the main method, that there is a mismatch exception.

Comment: @154guy It runs successfully for me. Please try refreshing it.

Comment: I must of entered in something wrong on my end, everything works! Thank you so much!

Comment: @154guy Your Welcome! :)